# WorkManager: Hide logs in the logcat

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I'm making an SDK which uses workManager to handle the background tasks. The thing is, I want my sdk to show the useful logcats I specify. But when I run a workManager task I get debug logs about SUCCESS, RETRY, etc of the workManager.

```
Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=44a0ed5d-69c5-4318-84eb-69680d1c3647, tags={ TaskPerformer, my_task } ]
```

Is there anyway to hide these logs since they are not useful for the developer who uses the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use `setMinimumLoggingLevel(android.util.Log.ASSERT)`.

It's may be kind of a hack since there's no "disable logging" in WorkManager's API AFAIK, but it'll get the job.

From the docs:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging